# re-register service provider in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, inversion-of-control

I am not sure if I am going about this the right way but here is what I am attempting to do, if there is a better way please let me know.

I am using a service provider that pulls some data from a config file. the problem is that if I use `Config::set` to change one of the settings after calling a function that uses that service provider it will not update. I thought that because I am using `app->bind` instead of `app->share` that it would re instantiate the class every time. here is my code:

service provider:

```
public function Register() {
  $app = $this->app;

  $app->bind('\path\to\MyInterface', function() use($app) {
     $server = $app['config']->get('myconfig.server');
     $client = $app['config']->get('myconfig.client');
     $key = $app['config']->get('myconfig.key');
     $version = $app['config']->get('myconfig.version');

     return new MyService(new Instance($server, $client, $key, $version));
  });

  $this->app->booting(function() {
     $loader = \Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader::getInstance();
     $loader->alias('MyServiceFacade', '\path\to\MyFacade');
  });
}
```

Facade class:

```
class MyServiceFacade extends Facade {

protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return '\path\to\MyInterface'; }
}
```

route for testing:

```
 Route::get('test', function() {
  $nodes = MyServiceFacade::allNodes(); 


  \Config::set('myconfig.server', 'new server name');
  $nodes2 = MyServiceFacade::allNodes(); 

  var_dump($nodes->getContent());
  var_dump($nodes2->getContent());
}
);
```

I am getting the same results from both. shouldn't this be using the update config since I am making a new instance of the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Skip to update 2 below for a stab at the answer*

Your question doesn't quite make sense.  In your testing route you're saying

```
App::make('MyController');
```

This is you asking Laravel to `make` an instance of the `MyController` service and/or class.  However, you never define a `MyController` service and/or class.

You bind a `\pathto\Interface` identifier here

```
$app->bind('\pathto\Interface', ...
```

and alias `MyService` to that identifier here

```
$loader->alias('MyService', '\pathto\Facade');
```

but there's no place you bind or alias a `MyController` identifier anywhere.  There's nothing in your code samples that tie `MyController` to the service you have bound.

Because of that it's not 100% clear what you're asking.

**Update**: Your question still doesn't quite make sense, and I think this not-sense-masking is what's leading the the unexpected behavior. i.e., you're doing something that "works", as in PHP doesn't complain with an error, but what you think is happening behind the scenes is not happening.

You've refereed to `MyService` as a facade -- however, you haven't told us what the "facade accessor" string the `MyService` facade points to (via its `getFacadeAccessor` method).  Also, you appear to be directly instantiating a class from that facade class (`new MyService`), which isn't how Laravel facades work.

**Update 2**: The code samples provided are still a little sketchy, and I suspect they don't accurately reflect the actual application.  The context from the comments are that `MyServiceFacade::allNodes` is a call to a facade.  However, the facade defined in the code samples is named `MyFacade` and there's no class `MyServiceFacade`.   I'm going to take a stab based on something mentioned in a comment as to the problem, but based on what I've seen above the problem still might be an incorrect application of service providers, services, and facades.

Binding a service with `bind` ensures **the application container** will always return a new instance of the service. I bet if you tried something like the following

```
$app = app();
$object = $app['\path\to\MyInterface'];
```

You'd find your object is instantiated anew every time.  Adding some basic `var_dump` debugging to the bound closure and/or service class constructor is a good way to confirm that.

**However**, Laravel facades are a little different.  They're not, technically, a part of the application container system.  Facades are a second system built on top of the application container.

In addition to providing a convenient alias for accessing a service class, the facade implementation also forces the service object into a single-instance/singleton **irrespective of how you've bound it into the container**.  This happens in the base facade class here

```
#File: vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php
protected static function resolveFacadeInstance($name)
{
    if (is_object($name)) return $name;

    if (isset(static::$resolvedInstance[$name]))
    {
        return static::$resolvedInstance[$name];
    }

    return static::$resolvedInstance[$name] = static::$app[$name];
}
```

The base facade class keeps an instance cache in `static::$resolvedInstance`. The specifics of how Laravel gets here are a bit long for a StackExchange answer, but my [Unraveling Laravel Facades](http://alanstorm.com/laravel_facades) article (part of [a longer series](http://alanstorm.com/category/laravel#container)) is a good place to start.

The problem here (again, based on the incomplete information provided) appears to be a misunderstanding of facades.  The main takeaway is **a facade always forces a service object to be a singleton**.

Comment: I figured the controller did not need to be posted since it is very generic and just routes back to the Facade(as i said in my comment), I am not having issues with inner workings of the facade or controller. I would just like to be able to change the config and have the service provider reloaded to use that new config

Comment: I have updated my code to be more clear, now I am directly calling the Facade

Comment: @arrowill12 Better, but still a little confusing.  Updated the answer with further clarifications.

Comment: I have updated the question again and included my facade class and changed the naming which may have been confusing. Again this is not an issue with facades or how to use them.  I want to be able to make multiple calls to `MyServiceFacade` and have it pick up the new config settings every time. currently the service provider is registered only once so the `app->bind` only happens on the initial call and does not update afterwards

Comment: @arrowill12 I think I see the question you're asking, but the code you've provided is still incorrect, so I'm not sure if the answer I provided in update 2 is what you're looking for.  Hope it helps, and good luck.

Comment: thank you for the update your answer in bold at the bottom is exactly what I was looking for "it forces a singelton". the code is not 100% accurate because I have changed the class names and thing to be more generic so people do not get hung up on the libraries i am using. in my application everything is correct as far as names and classes